# Bootstrap DateTimePicker 'dp.change' returns old value

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Im learning how to work with Bootstrap DateTimePickers, everything looks fine, except when I select a date I always get previous date instead of new one (selected one), so it seems the function gets triggered just before a date is selected, not after. But as I search around, it seems noone else experience this problem. Can anyone see what Im doing wrong with my test code below?

```
        $(function () {
            var year = new Date().getFullYear();
            var month = new Date().getMonth();
            var defaultDate = new Date(year, month, "1");

            $('#date-time-from').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: defaultDate,
                format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
            }).on('dp.change', function () {
                console.log($(this).data("DateTimePicker").date());
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. It actually works correctly. I just watched the output in console log and it seems bit odd to me. It just shows the original date and new date (chosen one) is just inside the moment object so u need to roll it out.

[screenshot console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5pov.png)